# Выгрузка из mysql в xml

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlconnector

Каким образом можно выгрузить информацию из разных таблиц в один xml файл?

Конечно я знаю, что нужно делать второй запрос к другой таблице, но придется закрыть тогда DataReader, а дальше уже ума не приложу , как лучше реализовать. Конечно можно было бы entity сделать, но так же без понятия каким образом можно выгружать информацию.

Пользуюсь - MySQL connector.

```
string documents = "Select * from documents where id > 716";
MySqlConnection mysql_connection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(documents, mysql_connection);        
mysql_connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader mysql_result;    
mysql_result = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
int i = 0;
while (mysql_result.Read())    
{
    i++;    
    XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();    
    XElement doc = new XElement("doc");
    xdoc.Add(doc);
    XElement news = new XElement("news", mysql_result.GetString("news"));
    doc.Add(news);
    XElement catl = new XElement("catl", mysql_result.GetString("catl"));      //вытаскивается только id столбца и тут как раз таки в этом теге понадобится     выгрузка из другой таблицы
    doc.Add(catl);
    xdoc.Save(i+"doc.xml");
}
mysql_result.Close();
mysql_connection.Close();
```

Comment: Добавте комментарий в вопрос - [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/679533/edit).

Comment: "но придется закрыть тогда `DataReader`" -  ридер из одной команды можно получить. Соответственно, если нужно несколько команд, то будет и несколько ридеров. А, вообще, не совсем понятно, что именно Вы сделать хотите? Приведите структуру таблиц, чтобы было более наглядно

Comment: @Jeron, используйте `join` или просто сохраните список `id`, а потом дополнительными запросами получаете детальные сведения по каждому id

Comment: А вообще, конечно, нужно составить объектную модель ваших данных, получить их из БД и потом уже с помощью Linq группировать как надо

Comment: @Sv__t, структура такова - есть две таблицы это documents и catalog. 
В documents есть поле - catl. Это поле ссылается на поле - id в таблице catalog. Т.е. второй запрос будет - select catalog.name from catalog where catalog.id IN(select documents.catl from documents).
Я пробовал открывать разные ридеры, но будет ругаться, тк в одном подключении можно использовать один ридер.

Comment: @Андрей, если закрыть ридер , то будут вылезать куча ошибок. Т.е. во первых я все делаю это в цикле while , тк в таблице documents много строк и соответственно, если я буду в цикле закрывать , то по итогу будет падать в исключение.
Во вторых -  при повторном открытии DataReader , чтение будет начинаться с первой строчки.

Comment: @Андрей, я думал через linq попробовать , но как именно это делать - я не знаю. Я гуглил на этот счет очень много, но ничего дельного не находил для себя. Модель я пробовал строить , но а дальше что? Как обращаться к модели БД ? Я не знаю.
И скорее это более удобный вариант.

Comment: @Андрей, я думал насчет "join" и понял, что мне не подходит такой вариант решения, тк мне в будущем понадобится вытаскивать не только из двух таблиц (documents и catalog), а потом еще и из трех и четырех таблиц.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос информацию о том, как у вас сейчас связаны таблицы. Судя по тому что я читаю в комментариях у вас связь `один-к-одному` (или в таблице `catalog` встречаются записи с одинаковым `id`?)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, а что мешает написать 1 select запрос, который вам выдаст сразу все необходимые данные? (структуры таблиц не знаю, пишу случайные имена полей)

```
string documents = "Select t1.doc, t1.news , t2.Name as catl
                    from document t1, catalog t2 
                    where t1.catl = t2.id" ;
MySqlConnection mysql_connection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(documents, mysql_connection);        
mysql_connection.Open();
MySqlDataReader mysql_result;    
mysql_result = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
int i = 0;
while (mysql_result.Read())    
{
 i++;    
 XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();    
 XElement doc = new XElement("doc");
 xdoc.Add(doc);
 XElement news = new XElement("news", mysql_result.GetString("news"));
 doc.Add(news);
 XElement catl = new XElement("catl", mysql_result.GetString("catl"));      
 doc.Add(catl);
 xdoc.Save(i+"doc.xml");
}
mysql_result.Close();
mysql_connection.Close();
```

Comment: тут дело в том, что одна таблица связана с другими таблицами и вызывать ридеры ,крайне, не очень удобно. Т.е. проблема в том, что нужно кучу запросов делать и одним select'ом не обойдешься к сожалению.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это не полный ответ на ваш вопрос, но все же:

Для начала вы должны создать класс под каждые возвращаемый набор данных.

Например, возвращаете вы ID,Name => делаете класс с такими же свойствами и помечаем его атрибутом `SerializableAttribute`.

Далее, вооружаемся `Dapper`'ом и делаем что-то вроде такого:

```
conn.Query<MyClass>("SELECT ID,Name FROM Table");
```

`Dapper` сам свяжет результаты запроса с нашей сущностью и вернет коллекцию данных. Только важно, что бы имена возвращаемых колонок были такими же.

Теперь у нас есть все необходимые данные.

Так... данные у нас есть. Осталось их превратить в XML => в этом нам поможет XML сериализация, которая нас избавит от ручной генерации XML.

Техника очень гибкая и можно с помощь различных атрибутов задавать всякие алиасы и прочие штуки.

Делаем так:

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
ser.Serialize(writer, myClass);
writer.Close();
```

И получаем, файл XML.

Если не нужен файл, то просто используем другой Writer.